# Why does this older git commit appear on the top?

Tags: git, git-svn

Consider the following git log. The commits are ordered by date. Yet there's one commit that is clearly older than others but still appears on the top.

```
commit f9afb9e89918faaff09686ce1df4a36f12e82693
Author: Kshitiz Sharma
Date:   Fri May 20 11:59:00 2016 +0100

    Deleted tags

commit f3b90300799878178c09841ccac7ffcd4c9cc4d9
Author: Kshitiz.Sharma
Date:   Fri Jun 10 13:00:32 2016 +0000

    Refactor some code

    git-svn-id: svn://1.1.1.1/myrepo@29029 ca623f4c-c864-0410-95d3-a40aa24e21c6

commit c98ad952b84403908ba656ab2f18af9a18a4f95c
Author: Kshitiz.Sharma
Date:   Wed Jun 8 14:35:29 2016 +0000

    Handle nullpointer exception

    git-svn-id: svn://1.1.1.1/myrepo@29010 ca623f4c-c864-0410-95d3-a40aa24e21c6
```

Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date of commits does not dictate the order of them. Three situations can create out-of-date-order commits:

1. A commit may have a fake date set
2. A commit may stem from a different branch and may have been introduced using a `merge` (the usual `git log` does not show merges).
3. A commit may have been moved around by a `rebase` (which moves the commit around in the graph of commits but leaves the original date intact)

Judging by the fact you are using `git-svn`, which does a lot of rebasing, I would guess it's a case of number 3.

Answer (score 2):

The commit on top was not forwarded to the SVN repository. It only exists in git. The other commits were sent to SVN (using [`git svn dcommit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn), as evidenced by their `git-svn-id`s).

When you pull the latest changes from SVN with `git svn rebase`, `git-svn` rearranges your commits and puts your local stuff on top of the (linear) SVN history. (That is, it literally [rebases](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) any commits SVN doesn't know about.)

Rebasing only rearranges the history. It doesn't change the commit dates.